# Monetization of an iOS app by he number of database entries it will support

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Consider an iOS application that lets you interact with your customers. I would like to charge the user of my app based on how many customers he has in his database. So he can use my app to manage 10 of his customers or 50 or 100 etc.

Is there a way to do an in app purchase like this?

Comment: Yes.  You could use a non-consumable IAP for a one-off "unlock" of a certain number of customers, or an auto-renewing subscription IAP for a recurring charge model.  Either way you would need to create a number of IAP products for the required tiers; e.g. 10,25,50,100 etc.  You can't stack multiple 10s to get 20 as you can only purchase each product once.  The advantage of a auto-renewing IAP is that you customer can upgrade/downgrade as their needs change

Comment: Thanks, Paulw11.  One follow-up.  One ramification in this model would be that if someone bought 10 and realized it was not enough - they really needed 20, then there is no way to offer an upgrade to 20 at an upgrade price...  i.e. they would have to buy the 20 'license' on top of the 10 they had already purchased...  So now they have paid for 10 and 20 but could have saved money if they had gone for the 20 originally.

Comment: Subscriptions can be better that way since the user can upgrade or downgrade subscriptions at any time. If they upgrade then they are immediately credited for the unused period of the lower tier and then charged for the higher tier. If they downgrade then they keep access to the higher tier until the next billing cycle and then they are charged less. You can also create "upgrade" non-consumable products and only display those when the relevant product is purchased (ie only display the "10-20 upgrade" if they have bought the "10".

Comment: awesome response.  Thanks, Paulw11.